# Parallel algorithms for reachability in directed planar graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, dc.parallel-comp

[Chong, Han and Lam](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=314500.314562) showed that undirected st-connectivity can be solved on the EREW PRAM in $O({\log}n)$ time with $O(m+n)$ processors.

What is the best known parallel algorithm for [st-connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity) in directed planar graphs ?

Please state the running time, deterministic/randomized algorithm and the PRAM model used (assuming the number of processors is polynomial).

This question is related to [one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/parallel-algorithms-for-directed-st-connectivity) of my previous questions. My [previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/parallel-algorithms-for-directed-st-connectivity) is about general directed graphs which are not necessarily planar.

Comment: it took me some clicking back and forth to realize that the difference was planarity. can you clarify that when you mention the previous question ?

Comment: I did the same thing as Suresh, and I took the liberty of editing the last sentence.  The word “general” is not very informative when the reader does not know what it is contrasted to (“planar” in this case).  I hope you do not mind….

Answer (score 3):

See

- Kao, Ming-Yang; Klein, Philip N. (1993), Towards overcoming the transitive-closure bottleneck: efficient parallel algorithms for planar digraphs, J. Comput. System Sci. 47 (1993), no. 3, 459–500.

Their Theorem 10 gives a deterministic CRCW algorithm for $st$-reachability in planar digraphs with $O(n)$ processors and $O(\log^3 n)$ time. Searching Google scholar for other papers that cited theirs, I didn't see anyone else with improvements to this.